# Where to find Linux drivers for my notebook

Tags: linux, drivers

Perhaps it is not proper to post on this forum. Sorry for any inconvenience.

I have finally make up my mind to use Linux (Ubuntu 10.04) as the SOLE operating system on my notebook. The last obstacle is that where to find proper drivers for my devices? Such as:

- ATI Xpress 200M Video Adapter
- Texas Instrument SD Card Reader
- And many more...

Could someone give me some advices on where to find these drivers?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is run `lspci -n` and paste the output into the box at http://kmuto.jp/debian/hcl/ - this gives the driver name and the kernel version required.

Comment: I have found all the pci devices on my box, now it's still a problem to find the proper drivers...

Answer (score 0):

For the **ATI Xpress** - Simply go to **System -> Admin -> Hardware Drivers** and you should see the driver. Make sure you have the xorg-driver-fglrx package installed.

For Texas Instrument SD Card Reader -  [go to](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=420721), as this explains the way to do it

For everything else simply install the OS, and see what works and what doesn't, its all a learning curve

Comment: I clicked the Hardware Drivers in the menu. But there's just a window flashing by with some updating information. And then disappears. Nothing else happened. I know that fglrx package is propriety driver from ATI. So does that symptom mean I have no fglrx driver? I know that ubuntu install open source 'ati' or 'radeon' driver for cards manufactured by ATI. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at [linuxhardware.org](http://linuxhardware.org/)